# Javascript or JQuery over scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a table body

```
<tbody id='displaylaps' class='scroll' style='width: 100%'></tbody>
```

Which fills with data and scrolls when it reaches a certain vertical length.

I wanted to have an over scroll effect like the effect after an iOS safari page ends and bounces back. Also needs to be iOS touch compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to accomplish this on iOS or in a desktop web browser?

For iOS, simply add this to your CSS:

```
#displaylaps {
  overflow: scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use [iScroll](http://cubiq.org/iscroll) library for desktop webkit browsers